# Power switch 12 KV

Tags: switches, high-power

I want to control a load which is working with 12000VDC (with low current about uA). Is there any kind of MOSFET or switch (not mechanical actually) for that to turn it on or off?
Is that possible at all?

**EDIT:**

[image]

I want to switch it on to charge the capacitor and then discharge it into my load.
The speed must be at least 12 times per minute.the switch will be on/off by a controller circuit like a uC

Comment: What is your application? Please provide more details and at least a schematic.

Comment: How quicly (or slowly) can power be switched on/off

Comment: @Andyaka see my Edit

Comment: @HL-SDK see my Edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a high voltage relay. It is mechanical but can switch at your frequencies and has a good contact lifetime.
http://www.gigavac.com/pdf/ds/hv/g15.pdf
GIGAVAC make other configurations such as SPST and higher/lower working voltages. I chose a SPDT since that is what you drew in your schematic.

As for semiconductors, I would advise against connecting devices in series. There are 4kV mosfets available, but generating the correct gate drive signals would prove to be an exercise in frustration.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the circuit for an ESD gun and from my experience a company called Jennings makes relays for such devices, operating up to 15kV. [Here](http://www.amstechnologies.com/fileadmin/amsmedia/downloads/4035_vacuumgasfilledrelays.pdf) a document that may prove useful. Here's a section of the document giving you a couple of model numbers BUT be prepared to pay hansomely for these: -

[image]